# IFNULL(COUNT('id'),0) in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I believe there is an error in this line in Codeigniter using Active Records, but I  cant seem to figure out the syntax on the second line with IFNULL() and COUNT()

```
$this->db->select('places.*, category.*')
            ->select('IFNULL(COUNT("places_reviews.place_id"), 0) AS num_reviews')
            ->from('places')
            ->join('category', 'places.category_id = category.category_id')
            ->join('places_reviews', 'places_reviews.place_id = places.id', 'left')
            ->where('places.category_id', $category_id)
            ->group_by('places.id')
            ->limit($limit, $offset)
            ->order_by($sort_by, $sort_order);
```

Comment: can't you use just one select method?

Comment: Shouldn't `COUNT("places_reviews.place_id")` be `COUNT(places_reviews.place_id)`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add `false` after the SELECT statement.  CodeIgniter is trying to escape the statement with backticks and doesn't know how to do so correctly.  The `false` will tell it not to.

```
->select('IFNULL(COUNT(`places_reviews.place_id`), 0) AS `num_reviews`', false)
```

**EDIT**: In `COUNT("places_reviews.place_id")`, the quotes should be backticks.