# multiple join in codeigniter not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

there is 4 table

option_group(id, optionGroupName)

category_optiongroup(categoryId, optionGroupId, inOrder)

product_option(productId, optionGroupId, optionId)

option(id, optionValue)

some products has not inserted its optionValue yet in the product_option table but I want to get theme all Whether is inserted or not.
for example size of specific product has not set yet.

here is my model but it only return all optionValue that is set.

is it some how possible to do it with IFNULL()? if not doesn't matter

IFNULL(optionValue, 'Not Set')

```
$this->db->select('option.optionValue')
   ->from('category_optiongroup')
   ->where('categoryId', $data['categoryId'])
   ->join('product_option', 'product_option.productId='.$productId.
      ' AND product_option.optionGroupId=category_optiongroup.optionGroupId', 'left')
   ->join('option', 'option.id=product_option.optionId')
   ->order_by('category_optiongroup.inOrder', 'ASC');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two tips:

1st: both ***option*** and ***product_option*** tables needs left join

2nd: certainly IFNULL() needs an alias to call

```
$this->db->select('IFNULL(`option`.`optionValue`, "Not Set") AS optionValue', FALSE)
   ->from('category_optiongroup')
   ->join('product_option', 'product_option.productId='.$productId
            .' AND product_option.optionGroupId=category_optiongroup.optionGroupId', 'left')
   ->join('option', 'option.id=product_option.optionId', 'left')
   ->where('categoryId', $data['categoryId'])
   ->order_by('category_optiongroup.inOrder', 'ASC');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query;
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IFNULL like this

```
$this->db->select('IFNULL(`option`.optionValue,"Not Set")',false)
   ->from('category_optiongroup')       
   ->join('product_option', 'product_option.productId='.$productId.
      ' AND product_option.optionGroupId = category_optiongroup.optionGroupId', 'left')
   ->join('`option`', '`option`.id=product_option.optionId')
   ->where('categoryId', $data['categoryId'])
   ->order_by('category_optiongroup.inOrder', 'ASC');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query;
```

Comment: missed one parentheses try the changed code

Comment: now when i want to return the result on controller i get Undefined property: stdClass::$optionValue

Comment: even this one not working```$this->db->select('option.optionValue')
   ->select('IFNULL(option.optionValue, "Not Set")', FALSE)```.(the error of undefinded property is gone but not showing the whole optionGroup like before)

Comment: it doesn't matter using IFNULL or not, just someone give proper answer please

Comment: you addeedd the jojn s behind the where cvlause that ios wrong, it must be before theorder and behind the joins

Comment: $this->db->select('option.optionValue')
   ->select('IFNULL(option.optionValue, "Not Set")', FALSE)
   ->from('category_optiongroup')
   ->join('product_option', 'product_option.productId='.$productId
   .' AND product_option.optionGroupId=category_optiongroup.optionGroupId', 'left')
   ->join('option', 'option.id=product_option.optionId')
   ->where('categoryId', $data['categoryId'])
   ->order_by('category_optiongroup.inOrder', 'ASC');
   $query = $this->db->get();
   return $query;

Comment: take look at this how this one works just fine [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940486/ifnullcountid-0-in-codeigniter) for him i mean

Comment: this is the same3 as i wrote you query has some bug that i can't odetify so run https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142099/how-to-print-sql-statement-in-codeigniter-model and see the queray as it is and see if it runs in workbench or

Comment: take look->__(SELECT `option`.`optionValue`, IFNULL(option.optionValue, "Not Set")
FROM `category_optiongroup`
LEFT JOIN `product_option` ON `product_option`.`productId`=174 AND `product_option`.`optionGroupId`=`category_optiongroup`.`optionGroupId`
JOIN `option` ON `option`.`id`=`product_option`.`optionId`
WHERE `categoryId` = '35'
ORDER BY `category_optiongroup`.`inOrder` ASC)

Comment: ran it in console still does not show the missing product-option that is not set yet

Comment: i get a error as  `option`m is a reserved word, so i dont' get where you get, try the code it should now run

Comment: with miner change adding backtick it is still return all of inserted options not the set part!

Comment: it always return inserted optionValue but not missed one as null (I want to show theme all in html table )